# GetResponseStream fails to recover following network failure

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

I am trying to write a resilient application that receives data from a local web server.  The code that reads the data is as follows:

```
     var myRequest =
           (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create(
                     "http://"+_ipAddress+
                     "/FileBrowser/Download?Path=/DataLogs/DataLogSmall.csv&RAW");

      myRequest.Referer = "http://"+_ipAddress+"/Portal/Portal.mwsl?PriNav=FileBrowser";
      var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myRequest.GetResponse();
      // Display the contents of the page to the console.
      Stream streamResponse = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

This code is surrounded by a try/catch block.  If the router is unplugged while the program is running, the following errors are thrown:

```
System.Net.WebExceptionL The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
```

This one makes sense, I pulled the plug on the router.

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

The above error continues while the router is unplugged.

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.
```

This (above) error happens when the router comes back on line.  It generally occurs once or twice

```
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
```

This error repeats forever.

If I stop and start the program, it works perfectly.
Any ideas?

Comment: The EntityException comes from a SQL connection. I cannot have originated here. Maybe you mixed up the source of the last error as well and something else threw it? Use the debugger set to halt on all exceptions to find out where exactly the exception is coming from and what input caused it.

Comment: That makes sense.  I wasn't tracking which line threw the exception.  Of course you can't connect to the SQL Server when the network is down.